# Why is my password not updated? ResetPasswordController

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, reset-password

When I try to reset an admin password, the token updates on password_resets_admin table, but password in my admin table does not. Reset email works, but when I fill the reset form (email, password, confirm password) and click reset password nothing happens.

Here is my code:

**ForgotPasswordController.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker;



class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset emails and
    | includes a trait which assists in sending these notifications from
    | your application to your users. Feel free to explore this trait.
    |
    */

    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;


    public function showLinkRequestForm()
    {
        return view('auth.passwords.email');
    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * password broker for admin guard.
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker(){
        return Password::broker('admins');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication
     * after password reset.
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    public function guard(){
        return Auth::guard('apipanel');
    }

    
}
```

**Auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'apipanel',
        'passwords' => 'admins',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'firebase',
        ],

        'apipanel' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets_admin',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

    ],

];
```

**Admin.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword;


class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
  use Notifiable;
  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
  ];
  /**
   * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
  ];


}
```

**web.php**

```
    <?php


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::get('/panel', 'Panel\\Panel@muestraPanelGeneral')->name('main');

Route::get('/panelProducers', function() {
    return view('panelProducers');
});

Route::get('/panelChannels', function() {
    return view('panelChannels');
});

Route::get('/panelPerfiles', 'Panel\\Panel@muestraPanelPerfiles');
Route::get('/panelOfertas', 'Panel\\Panel@muestraPanelOfertas');
Route::get('/panelPreOfertas', 'Panel\\Panel@muestraPanelPreOfertas');
Route::get('/panelClients', 'Panel\\Panel@muestraPanelClientes');

Route::get('/panelNewPolicies', 'Panel\\Panel@muestraPanelNewPolizas');
Route::get('/panelPolicies', 'Panel\\Panel@muestraPanelPolizas');
Route::get('/panelHelp', 'Panel\\Panel@muestraPanelHelp');

Route::get('/exportUsers', 'Panel\\ConfigController@export');
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\\LoginController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\\LoginController@login')->name('login');
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
Route::get('/', 'Panel\\HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset1/', 'Auth\\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('reset');


Route::get('/register', function() {
    return view('auth.register');
})->name('register');
Route::post('/register/', 'Auth\\RegisterController@register');





Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

**ResetPasswordController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker;



class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

   


    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/login';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
    {
        return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    protected function broker(){
        return Password::broker('admins');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
 
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('apipanel');
    }







    public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, $this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

        // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
        // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
        // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
            $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            }
        );

        // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
        // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
        // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
        return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                    ? $this->sendResetResponse($response)
                    : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }
}
´´´
```

Comment: please explain `nothing happens` Do you get error? Where are you redirected? What gets or doesn't get updated?

Comment: As well you do not provide the code for your `ResetPasswordController.php` but for your `ForgotPasswordController `

Comment: Hi Christophe! I don't get any error, and it redirects me to the same page with the same form. It saves the token on my password_resets_admin, but password on admins table doesn't change. I have the same problem as this user I guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59369050/laravel-reset-password-not-resetting-the-password

Comment: check that the Request $request has the new password you passed

Comment: I'm kinda new to laravel, could you explain to me how to do that?

Comment: in your `ResetPasswordController` edit `public function reset(Request $request){ dd($request->all()); ...`

Comment: Thanks! I did it, it returns me this :^ array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "IckLFnTO6c9bno8R3Jm9uy8R0HPe385V2GpZ17zk"
  "token" => null
  "email" => "usuario@admin.com"
  "password" => "123456"
  "password_confirmation" => "123456"
]

It seems ok, I don't know why in token says null

Comment: Solved it. This route : Route::get('password/reset1/', 'Auth\\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset') is wrong because it doesnt have the token in url, changed it to Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset') and works like a charm. Thanks guys!!